# My footer correctly repositions itself for almost every screen size, except one?

Tags: html, css, positioning

So I've been testing how my website looks with different screen sizes and I noticed my footer is positioned correctly at the bottom right of the screen for resolutions  800x600 to 1920x1080 BUT on 2560x1600 it does NOT position at the bottom right
/w h y/ ?

Im using CrossBrowserTesting

Here's my code:

```css
body {
    font-family: 'Courier New', Courier, monospace;
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #1D4350 , #A43931);
    background-attachment: scroll;
}
html, body, #wrapper {
    max-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    min-width: 960px; 
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#wrapper {
    position: relative;
}
#content {
    height: 1200px;
}
.Octagon { 
    color: #2aa186;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 30%;
    margin-top: 25px;
}
.LT {
    text-align: center;
    color: #3a5454;
    line-height: 0%;
    font-style: italic;
}
.boi {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 16px;
}
.boi:active {
    top: 2px;
}
.iob {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-left: 30px;
  padding: 8px 18px;
  border: 1px solid #204156;
  border-color: #52AEC9;
  color: #52AEC9;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
}
#verr {
    
}
.boi:active, 
.iob:active {
    top: 2px;
}
#manyarms {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 31px;
}
#sensible {
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 30px;
    margin-right: 31px;
    right: 10px;
}
.boi:hover,
.iob:hover {
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #a193ff;
}
#footer {
    padding-left: 93%;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
        <title>The Pragmatic Octopus</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
     <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
     <script src='script.js'></script> 
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
     <h1 class="Octagon">The Pragmatic Octopus</h1>
     <p class="LT">Lee Townsend</p>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="boi">Contact</p>
        </a>
        <a href="www.google.com">
     <p class="iob">Information</p>
        </a>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <div id="manyarms">
        <img src="https://s32.postimg.org/406x38nlh/imageedit_1_3827627792        .jpg" alt="mmm~" style="width:310px; height:250px;">
        <p style="color: #6458b7;" id="verr">Here comes a very special boi!</p>
    </div>
    <div id="sensible">
        <img src="http://www.wonderslist.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/Blue-ringed-octopus.jpg" alt="~mmm" style="width:310px; height:250px;">
        <p style="color:#6458b7;">He loves to pose for photos!</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="footer">
    &copy; Hecc
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Is this an error in my code or this a bug in CrossBrowserTesting?
Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

your #wrapper streches and its css is - max-width: 100%;
and your #footer is inside the #wrapper
soo maybe your content doesnt stretch the wrapper to full width and thats why the #footer isnt in the far right of screen(because its in far right of #wrapper)
try to take #footer out of #wrapper OR make #wrapper width:100% and body and html width:100%

Answer (score 0):

If you replace your :

```
#footer {
    padding-left: 93%;
}
```

with

```
#footer {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 10px;
}
```

You will fix your div on the right and that regardless if the screen is large, medium or small.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this code keeps the footer always on completely on the right!  I found the actual problem was that my footer was wrapped in a height setting of 1300~ pixels so it went to the bottom of that instead of the website.